# Insert more than one hyperlink in HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<ul>

      <ul>
      <? for (var jj = 0; jj < Data_Split.length; jj++) { ?>

      <li><a href="<?=Data_Split[jj]?>" target="_blank"> Enclosure</a></li> 

      <? } ?>
      </ul>

</ul>
```

Above code is an excerpt of code that I am using to insert hyperlinks in one cell of a HTML table. This HTML table is being drawn on basis of template stored in a file. The URLs are stored in array Data_Split[]. On publishing the code links are being displayed in relevant cell of the HTML table. But only the first link opens-up linked document. Other links re-open the table on clicking instead of opening the linked document. Why are other links not responding properly?

Comment: why do you have a javascript for loop within php tags and you're trying to print a JS variable within more php tags?! Also php shorthand tags should be avoided.

Comment: I am using google script. In fact the code is being published from Google Script editor. Both google script and HTML files are edited & published in the editor. Google Script has a lot in common with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You're using PHP wrong way... Here is proper code:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($Data_Split as $url) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $url ?>" target="_blank"> Enclosure</a></li> 
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

But if you meant to use JavaScript then you should do it this way:

```
<script>
var code = '<ul>';
for(var jj = 0; jj < Data_Split.length; jj++) { 
      code += '<li><a href="' + Data_Split[jj] + '" target="_blank"> Enclosure</a></li> 
}
code += '</ul>';
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Please don't post signatures within your posts here on StackOverflow. 2. Advertising is not allowed. If you have a website which you want to link to you can do so through your profile page.

Comment: Thanks Htmlin.com! I cannot use PHP as I am working in Google Script editor which works on Google Script. Google Script has a lot in common with Javascript. The javascript code given above is not working. Relevant cell remains blank. It seems the code needs to be modified for HTML template file format.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>

  <ul>
  <? for (var $jj = 0; $jj < sizeof($Data_Split); $jj++) { ?>

  <li><a href="<?=$Data_Split[$jj]?>" target="_blank"> Enclosure</a></li> 

  <? } ?>
  </ul>

</ul>
```

now its all in PHP, assuming your array is in php. if it's in javascript, you should do it different.
is it in PHP or JS?

Comment: Thanks Omri! The array is in javascript. I cannot use PHP as I am working in Google Script editor which works on Google Script. Google Script has a lot in common with Javascript.